# error while reading serially incoming data to plot live graph

Tags: python

My input data is like 36,45,32
so when I tried to replace comma by '.' i.e dot, so that it doesn't give me a "cannot convert to float" error, the conversion now would be 36.45.32, which is still not plottable on a live graph.

My code is:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import serial as sr

#------global variables
data = np.array([])
cond = False

#-----plot data-----
def plot_data():
    global cond, data
    
    if (cond == True):
        
        x= s.read()
        y=x.decode()
        
    
        a=y.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(',','.')
        print(a)
        
        
        if(len(data) < 100):
            data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))
        else:
            data[0:99] = data[1:100]
            data[99] = float(a[0:4])
        
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0,len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)
        
        canvas.draw()
    
    root.after(1,plot_data)

def plot_start():
    global cond
    cond = True
    s.reset_input_buffer()

def plot_stop():
    global cond
    cond = False
    

#-----Main GUI code-----
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Real Time Plot')
root.configure(background = 'light blue')
root.geometry("700x500") # set the window size

#------create Plot object on GUI----------
# add figure canvas
fig = Figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100),ylim=(0, 120)); #displaying only 100 samples
ax.set_title('Serial Data');
ax.set_xlabel('Sample')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage')
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5,6)
lines = ax.plot([],[])[0]

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 10,y=10, width = 500,height = 400)
canvas.draw()

#----------create button---------
root.update();
start = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", font = ('calbiri',12),command = lambda: plot_start())
start.place(x = 100, y = 450 )

root.update();
stop = tk.Button(root, text = "Stop", font = ('calbiri',12), command = lambda:plot_stop())
stop.place(x = start.winfo_x()+start.winfo_reqwidth() + 20, y = 450)

#----start serial port----
s = sr.Serial('COM5',9600);
s.reset_input_buffer()



root.after(1,plot_data)
root.mainloop()
```

Now the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Indu shekar\Desktop\ggg.py", line 26, in plot_data
    data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

at times it gives me error `" a bytes like object is required not string"`
please suggest the changes in my code

Comment: Is `36,45,32` meant to be three consecutive numbers, or just one with some unusual semantics? If it's three numbers, consider using split() to split them into a list of three numbers. If it's funky semantics, please let us know what semantics you expect.

Comment: Also, can you show what `print(a)` output when you got the error you show here?

Comment: The input coming from the microcontroller is 33,44,55, the output i want to be plotted on graph is 33,45,55 i.e 3 separate values to be plotted, subplots is also acceptable . The output I get when i print (a) is  33.45.32 as I've told replace , by .

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: based on the comments, I'm significantly revising my answer.

I first thought `"36,42,45"` was meant to be `float(36.42)`, ignoring the `45` part, but now you've clarified that it should be interpreted as `x=36`, `y=42` and `z=45`.

The updated solution I propose is to split `a` on comma and map each part to a float:

```py
x, y, z = (float(v) for v in a.split(","))
```

Taking it apart:

- `a.split(",")` returns a list of the comma-separated parts -> `['36', '42', '45']`
- `(float(v) for v in ...)` maps each element to a float using a comprehension -> `(36.0, 42.0, 45.0)`. Use `int(v)` instead of `float(v)` if you want the numbers to be used as ints instead of floats.
- `x, y, z = ...` unpacks the values into three variables.
  and then you can use `x`, `y` and `z` as you need to in your plotting code.

Warning: this will raise an exception if the list has either fewer or more than 3 comma-separated values, or if those values cannot be converted to floats.

Comment: Reading your question again, I suspect this won't work. I tested your code and if `a` was really a string like you show, it worked for me, so now I think we need to know more about your exact input. Maybe you need a regular expression to find the number in `y`?

Comment: Actually my data is just numbers like 33,45,67 coming from a microcontroller, and i just want to plot these numbers somehow on a live graph simultaneously,it can plotted like x vs y and x vs z,so you'll have 2 moving lines on your graph@ joanis

Comment: So, if `a` contains `x,y,z`, maybe all you need is `x, y, z = (float(n) for n in a.split(","))`? That's only going if work if you have exactly two commas, and numbers around them, with nothing else, but if that's your input it should help you.

Comment: So now I'm getting the error "float object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
This is how i changed my code ,please let me know how to make the changes as I'm not sure how to replace 'a'.
  y=x.decode()
   try:
    x, y, z = (float(n) for n in y.split(","))
    except:
           print('error')
            if(len(data) < 100):
            data = np.append(data,x,y)
            data=np.append(data,z)
        else:
            data[0:99] = data[1:100]
            data[99] = x,y,z
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0,len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)

Comment: value = float(".".join(y.split(",",3)[0:2])) ,this actually worked but the problem is 22,34,56 was taken as 22.34 and 56 which is not what i want although it was plotted

Comment: Reading your comments more thoroughly, it looks like you already did what I'm suggesting in my editted answer. The error "float object cannot be interpreted as an integer" suggests you should use `(int(n) for n in ...)` instead of `(float(n) for n in ...)`.

Comment: float() argument must be a  string or number, not list, give me some way how i can  ignore  comma and plot each of  (33,45,67) as in plot 33 with respect to i and then another line plotting 45  with respect i where i=i+1, so in my graph window there will be 3 separate lines.